# How do I use API keys, and token schemes effectively to secure REST API?

Tags: api, security, rest

I know this question has been asked a lot of times in varying shapes and forms, but I'm still quite unclear about a few things. It's confusing how resources about this topic around the Web refer to "user" without clear context. API keys are issued for users, and so are access tokens, but I don't think API key users, are the same as access token users.

- Do you need to have different API keys for different instances of end user clients? For example if I build a mobile app for a third party API, does each instance keep their own API key? I don't think they do, but how do I tie API keys, and access tokens together to say that a certain request comes from this particular instance of an app authorized by a known user? If I were the auth provider, do I have to keep track of each of those?
- API keys, and access tokens are usually represented by a pair of public, and shared keys. As a service provider (server side), which one do I use to verify the message I receive, the API key, or the access token? If I understand correctly, the idea is that each request should come with a signature derived from the secret part of the API key so that the server can check that it comes from a trusted client. Now what use do I have for access token secret? I know the access token is used to verify that a system user has authorized the app to carry operations on their behalf, but which part of the message does the access token secret be useful for?
- Is a hash generated from a (secured) random number, and a time stamp salt a good API key generation strategy?
- Are there (preferably open source, Java-based) frameworks that do most of these?

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to answer as many of your queries as I can.

**Apikey vs Access Token usage**

- First of all, apikeys are not used per user. Apikeys are assigned per
  application (of a developer). A developer of a service signs up their application and obtains a
  pair of keys.
- On the other hand access tokens are issued for each
  end-user in context of the usage (exception is Client Credential
  grant).
- Service providers can identify the application from the
  apikey in use.
- Service providers can identify the end-users using
  access token attributes.
- You should have any end-user APIs, that is an API that has end-user resources (data or context) associated, protected by 3 legged Oauth. So access token should be necessary for accessing those resources.
- Developer-only resources can be protected by apikey or two-legged Oauth. Here I am referring to Oauth2 standards.
- Oauth1 is preferred when there is no HTTPS is supported. This way the shared secret is not sent over unprotected channel. Instead it is used to generate a signature. I strongly suggest Oauth2 over HTTPs and avoid Oauth1 for ease of use. You and your API consumers would find Oauth2 to be much more simpler to implement and work with. Unless you have a specific reason to use Oauth v1

As a service provider you can use Apigee's Edge platform that provides Oauth 1 and 2. It is not opensource. However you can use it for free, until you need some high TPS or higher SLAs.

Comment: So does that mean for any resource that requires user authentication, the signature should be signed using the access token's secret? Does the token (the pair of keys) then represent the authorization granted by the user to the app? In the case the app has different instances (e.g. same application on different Android devices), does that mean all of them are authorized automatically? Hmm... well except those other instances wouldn't know the secret unless it's kept in a central backend they all use.

Comment: Yes to first two questions, assuming you are talking about Oauth 1 .  But remember there is no reason to not to allow more than one credentials set for a single application. That depends on the service provider's design.